# add key to indexed array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array

```
$array=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
```

and I have a start time and end time and I want result booked or available like the following array

```
Array
    (
        [availiable] => 09:00
        [availiable] => 09:30
        [booked] => 10:00
        [booked] => 10:30
        [availiable] => 11:00
        [availiable] => 11:30
        [availiable] => 12:00
        [availiable] => 12:30
        [availiable] => 12:30
    )
```

I tried following code but not worked

```
$array=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
    $start = "09:40";
    $end = "10:30";
$tmp = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) {
     if($arr=="09:30") {
             $tmp['booked'] = $arr;
      }
    else
    {
        $tmp['availiable'] = $arr;
    }
}

$ss=array_merge($array,$tmp);   
echo "<pre>";print_R($ss);
```

Comment: You can't have multiple array items with the same index

Comment: Mission Impossible

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone : is there any other way ? i just want to know booked or availiable time from array values

Comment: `[ ['available', '09:00' ], [ ... ], ... ]` Your `if`/`else` looks weird.

Comment: Are the time values unique in the array, you can do the reverse way, `if ($arr=="9:30") {$tmp[$arr] = "booked";} ` or you can group them: `if ($arr=="10:00" || $arr=="10:30") {$tmp["booked"][] = "$arr";} `

Comment: multiple keys share the same name, you can't do this. For example there are multiple `$tmp['availiable']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have the multiple identical keys in an array. However you can achieve a workable result using this code. It uses [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to process each element in the `$cars` array to determine if the time is booked or available; that result is then combined using the values of `$cars` as keys using [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$cars=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");
$start = "09:40";
$end = "10:30";
$availability = array_combine($cars, array_map(function ($v) use ($start, $end) { 
    return (strtotime($v) < strtotime($start) || strtotime($v) > strtotime($end)) ? 'available' : 'booked'; }, 
    $cars));
print_r($availability);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [09:00] => available
    [09:30] => available
    [10:00] => booked
    [10:30] => booked
    [11:00] => available
    [11:30] => available
    [12:00] => available
    [12:30] => available
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/X74RO)

Comment: `$start='09:40'`

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thanks, have updated answer, output and demo

Comment: This approach does make sense!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create multiple identical keys, this is impossible, because if you reference `$array['available']` then which one should it show? unknown!

Anyway, I would suggest creating two keys, one `booked` and one `available` - that way you have times stored in there.

**Example:**

```
$array=array("09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30");

$start = "09:40";
$end = "10:30";

$times = array();
foreach ($array as $time) {
  if($time=="09:30") {
    $times['booked'][] = $time;
  } else {
    $times['availiable'][] = $time;
  }
}

print_r($times);
```

**Results in:**

```
Array
(
    [availiable] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09:00
            [1] => 10:00
            [2] => 10:30
            [3] => 11:00
            [4] => 11:30
            [5] => 12:00
            [6] => 12:30
        )

    [booked] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09:30
        )

)
```